# Extra Apostrophes surrounding my string

Tags: python, printing

I try the following code:

```
print(repr("%0.2f" % cost).rjust(24), repr("%0.2f" % provision).rjust(17), end="\n")
```

but the resulting string I get is (when cost = 100.00 and provision = 4.00)

```
            '100.00'            '4.00'
```

So `r.just` is working perfectly (looked it up in here) but for some odd reason these apostrophes appeared around the values.

this doesn't happen in my next line of code:

```
print("Provision summ %0.2f euros." % summ)
```

which gives me

```
Provision summ 4 euros.
```

As you can see, no apostrophes, why is that? Can you advise me how to remove them? I have tried adding `.remove("'", "")` to my string, but it didn't help.

Comment: Hint: What does `repr` do?

Comment: did you mean `remove(""'"")`?

Comment: @Wilhelmsen: That's either too many or too few quotes; not valid Python as it stands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `repr()` here; it introduces the quotes because you are asking for the Python literal form of the strings. The `end='\n'` is entirely redundant too as that is the default. Grouping the format strings in parenthesis would do what you want:

```
print(("%0.2f" % cost).rjust(24), ("%0.2f" % provision).rjust(17))
```

or justifying *before* interpolating:

```
print("%0.2f".rjust(24) % cost, "%0.2f".rjust(17) % provision)
```

You perhaps would do better studying [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and use that to format and justify your text:

```
print("{:>24.2f}{:>18.2f}".format(cost, provision))
```

Here the `>24` and `>18` right-justify the value in a field 24 and 18 characters wide (the latter is 17 + the extra space `print()` adds when printing multiple arguments):

```
>>> cost, provision = 100.0, 4.0
>>> print("{:>24.2f}{:>18.2f}".format(cost, provision))
                  100.00              4.00
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, obviously i had not understood what i had read about r.just() and repr() and that's why my code looks so messed up, but for now i got my code working just the way i wanted it to, and now i will go ahead and study the str.format() you mentioned. 
Thank you so much for helping me out Pieters!

Answer (score 1):

That's what `repr` does, though: shows a representation of the actual object. In this case, the object is the string composed of `"%0.2f" % cost` etc.

I have no idea why you would use `repr` here at all, especially when you're not doing so in the next, correct, line. It should just be:

```
print(("%0.2f" % cost).rjust(24) ... )
```

Answer (score 1):

Why that double formatting (i. e. using `%0.2f` first and then again using `rjust`)?  You can do that in one step, that's what it is meant for:

```
print('%24.2%17.2f' % (cost, provision))
```

This is probably what you want.